# Spring Boot support maven multi-module

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to convert my existing multi-module maven Spring project to Spring Boot project. The reason is make it self contain and follow Martain Fowler's [microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) concept.

However, the problem I have encounter is when try to clean build, seems the spring boot is trying to find the Main method from every module, which of course will failed.

Is this feature currently supported by Spring Boot 1.1.6.RELEASE or I did something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code? Also how are you trying to lanch the application?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've added Spring Boot's Maven plugin to every module in your build – it's what's looking for a main method. You should only add the Spring Boot plugin to a module if its a service that you want to run. If the module's just code that's shared between your services, the Spring Boot plugin isn't needed in that module.